# Laravel deploy fails because migrate

Tags: php, laravel, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

This is part of my deployment script which unfortunately fails:

```
image: php:7-fpm

pipelines:
  branches:  # Pipelines that run automatically on a commit to a branch
    staging:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip python-dev git
            - apt-get install -qy git curl libmcrypt-dev mysql-client
            - docker-php-ext-install mcrypt && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
            - ./install-composer.sh
            - composer install
            - export APP_ENV=QA
            - export S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AAAAA
            - export S3_BUCKET_ASSETS=AAAAA
            - export S3_DEFAULT_CDN_BASE=AAAAA
            - export S3_REGION=eu-west-1
            - export S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=AAAAA
            - curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
            - python get-pip.py
            - pip install awsebcli --upgrade
            - eb init this-data -r eu-central-1 -p PHP
            - eb setenv APP_ENV=QA JS_PATH=AAAA IMAGES_PATH=AAAAA FONTS_PATH=AAAA                - eb setenv SES_KEY=AAAAA
            - eb printenv
            - export CACHE_DRIVER=redis
            - export SESSION_DRIVER=redis
            - export DB_CONNECTION=mysql
            - php artisan migrate
            - php artisan serve
            - eb deploy this-staging-env
          services:
            - mysql

definitions:
      services:
              mysql:
                image: mysql
                environment:
                  MYSQL_DATABASE: 'thisdb'
                  MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
                  MYSQL_USER: 'thisuser'
                  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'thispass'
                  MYSQL_HOST: 'rdsInstance'
```

The message that comes up is:

```
php artisan migrate
```

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations)
>     at /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/

Comment: Ensure your database details are correct and you are using the correct mysql port for your environment, seems it cannot connect to the database.

Comment: Would that be the only reason that migrate would fail? In this case, I would expect a more meaningful failure message.

Comment: Actually I may be mistaken, take a look at this (obviously you won't be using sqlite but it may shed some light on your issue) https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-artisan-migrate-gives-me-an-error-could-not-find-driver

Comment: You might be correct actually as I also see `Exception trace:
PDOException::("could not find driver")
      /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php : 68
  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=forge", "forge", "", [])`

Comment: Did you create a database called `forge`? with a user account of `forge` and NO PASSWORD?????????

Comment: Actually, no. The DB that I am trying to connect to is different

Comment: @thitami the "could not find driver" part tells me it cannot use MySQL, you could try installing `php7.0-mysql` and test the connection then

Comment: @HelloSpeakman But it's already done here:  - apt-get install -qy git curl libmcrypt-dev mysql-client
            - docker-php-ext-install mcrypt && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql 
and according to the official docs: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/laravel-with-bitbucket-pipelines-913473967.html

Comment: @thitami I'm not sure if those packages actually include `php7.0-pdo` or  `php7.0-mysql` - worth a try to install them specifically to get a working database driver for laravel. Sorry I can't be any more help.

Comment: Thanks @HelloSpeakman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add this in .ebextensions/init.config:

```
container_commands:
    01initdb:
        command: "php artisan migrate"
```

Which means that the migrate command runs after the deploy.